# How to prove that the spectrum of the Laplacian over $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is negative?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory

I am looking for a proof of this well known fact and I guess it has to do with integration by parts (Green's identity). Unfortunately, I only know about 1-d integration by parts( I am just 3rd semester). could anybody sketch a short proof that shows that the spectrum of the Laplacian is negative?

My problem with the hint that brom gave me is that I do not know what I can assume about this surface integral and so on that appear in green's identity, but maybe I am looking at this from the wrong direction.

If I start:

$$ \int_V u \Delta u + \underbrace{\langle \nabla u, \nabla u \rangle}_{\ge 0} = \int_{\partial V}u(\nabla u n) dS$$
I mean intuitively, the thing is, that if we assume that our function $\psi$ vanishes at infinity and we integrate over the whole space, then the surface integral is maybe zero. In this case, we had 
$$ \int_V u \Delta u=-\int_V\langle \nabla u, \nabla u \rangle \le 0$$
But I do not see the correct mathematical reasoning behind this!

Comment: The Laplacian on $\mathbb{R}^n$ does not have any eigenvalues. However if you meant the Laplacian on a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the corresponding formula is Green's Identity (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities). You can also use this formula to prove that the spectrum (which contains no eigenvalues) of the Laplacian on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is negative.

Comment: @brom yeah, I want to prove the second thing you mentioned there, but I do not see how to apply these identities to the laplacian. do you think you could give me the proof as an answer.

Comment: @Lipschitz: spectrum of a linear operator $T$ is the set of $\lambda \in {\bf C}$ such that $T-\lambda I$ doesn't have continuous inverse.

Comment: yeah, but those lambdas are exactly the eigenvalues aren't they? so why did brom correct me?

Comment: can you prove that the spectrum is negative?

Comment: okay, I think I get it, just because $T-\lambda I$ is not invertible, it does not have be an eigenvalue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As brom already pointed out in the comments, for a bounded domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, if $\lambda $ is a *Dirichlet* eigenvalue for Laplacian: 
$$
\Delta u = \lambda u \; \text{ in }\Omega,
\\
u = 0 \text{ on }\partial \Omega.\tag{1}
$$
Then
$$
\lambda \int_{\Omega} u^2 = \int_{\Omega} u\Delta u = - \int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^2 + \color{blue}{\int_{\partial \Omega} u(\nabla u\cdot n)\,dS},
$$
where blue term vanishes and we get the Rayleigh quotient for Laplacian: for non-trivial $u$ solving (1)
$$
\lambda = - \frac{\int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^2}{\int_{\Omega} u^2 } <0.
$$
For *Neumann* eigenvalues we have the first one being 0 and others being negative, in that there exists a non-trivial function $\Delta u =0 $ and $\nabla u\cdot n = 0$.

---

> My problem with the hint that brom gave me is that I do not know what I can assume about this surface integral and so on that appear in Green's identity.

A key part here for either Dirichlet or Neumann eigenvalues for Laplacian, is to assume proper boundary conditions so that the boundary surface integral will vanish.

Comment: ah, did not know that this is the right way to think about it